# Prove that ∀n≥1, (1/(1⋅3))+(1/(3⋅5))+(1/(5⋅7))+...+(1/(2n−1)(2n+1)) =( n/(2n+1))|

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove that  ∀n≥1,  (1/(1⋅3))+(1/(3⋅5))+(1/(5⋅7))+...+(1/(2n−1)(2n+1)) =( n/(2n+1))|

So, I understand that the proof must display that (1/(2n−1)(2n+1) is equivalent to (1/(2n−1)(2n+1).

Would I solve this by induction?

If this is the case, I would first do a Base Case, by positioning n to 0 (or would I do 1 because ∀n≥1?)
In the case of 1, (1/(2−1)(2+1) =( 1/(2+1))

```
                        1/3=1/3
```

Therefore, the base case would be true.

However, I then get confused at this point.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Just suggesting another approach.

If you are familiar with partial fraction, notice that, 
$$\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac12\left( \frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k+1} \right)$$

Using telescoping sum, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac12\left( \frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k+1} \right)=\frac12\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+1} \right)=\frac{n}{2n+1}$$

Comment: You cannot prove the second equality in your last sentence without using induction.

Comment: @user21820, I disagree, there is no explicit use of induction here. The poster doesn't guess the answer and then prove it using induction. As for implicit induction, used here for telescoping, you can as well say we use induction every time we use natural numbers.

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: Most people don't realize that the basic properties of summation require induction, so they claim that no induction is being used, which is simply false. Also, no, not every statement provable about the natural numbers requires induction...

Comment: @user21820, I understand your point

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{n}{2n+1}$$

Induction hypothesis, suppose that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{n-1}{2n-1}$$

Can you see that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{n-1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}=\frac{n}{2n+1}?$$